# How to split a string and convert it into an array of floats

Tags: c++

I want to convert the string into a float array
They are saved as double strings
Thanks for your help

```
string str ="7.13566982194977e-15,1.639519203260036e-43,4.149314136725479e-8,7.987401246651457e-44,7.11674964700695e-15,1.639519203260036e-43,4.515206005147025e+27"

std::vector<float> result
```

Comment: Use `std::istringtream` and `std::getline` with a custom separator.

Comment: OT: you're going to be a bit disappointed when `float` doesn't provide the precision you may be expecting...

Comment: @Fe2O3 yes That's what I'm most worried about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::istringstream(str);     // #include <sstream>
std::string s;
std::vector<float> result;
while (std::getline(str, s, ','))
{
    float f = atof(s.c_str());
    result.push_back(f);
}
```

Comment: Probably because you answer a question that has a billion different duplicates (not the downvoter)